# Python nested dict comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, list-comprehension

I have a dictionary:

```
my_dict = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

And I want a comprehension like `add_dict = (x x +1 for x my_dict)`
what would be the best approach to take when writing a comprehension to deal with keys with multiple values?

So the output would look like `{'a': [2, 3, 4], 'c': 4, 'b':3}` or maybe I might want to only `+1` to values `1` and `2` of each key, keys `'b'` and `'c'` ... would be skipped.

I tried this (first two lines are kind redundant / was messing about)

```
my_dict = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
    D = {x: y for (x, y) in zip(my_dict.keys(), my_dict.values())}
    test = (v for v in D.values())

    for x in test:
        try:
            if len(x):
               for i in x:
                   print i +1
        except:
            print x +1
```

if **name** == '**main**':
    main()
output was

2
3
4
object of type 'int' has no len()
object of type 'int' has no len()

I was trying to find a more elegant way of doing this that worked using comprehensions.

Comment: It's not exactly clear to me what you want to obtain... Should all integers increment? Please show the expected result.

Comment: Furthermore is it possible that the list is also **nested**? Is `my_dict = {'a': [1,[2,3],5]}` possible?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far (forming a [mcve]), example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: "*or maybe I might want to only +1 to values 1&2 of each key, keys 3 and 4 ... would be skipped.*". Well you need to know first what you want to do...

Comment: Please post the expected output along with the solution you tried.

Comment: here is what i tried.

Comment: Side-note: `zip(my_dict.keys(), my_dict.values())` is a really verbose way to say `my_dict.items()`... And given this is Python 2, you could just use `my_dict.iteritems()` and drop from three temporary `list`s you don't need to zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a one-liner for you (in Python 3), assuming the dictionary values never become double-nested:

```
>>> {k:([x+1 for x in v] if not isinstance(v,int) else v+1) for k,v in my_dict.items()}
{'a': [2, 3, 4], 'b': 3, 'c': 4}
```

Replace `my_dict.items()` with `my_dict.iteritems()` for Python 2

Comment: Thanks I had done it without comprehension which I guess was the first step. I added what I did to this post